# Version control in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have been reading about version control in enterprise architect. Here is a small scenario that I have. Can anyone please tell me how enterprise architect behaves in such a situation.

1. Suppose the package is being shared by 3 users and the package has a number of classes each having some activity diagrams and state machines.
2. Incase a user A makes any changes to one of the state machines and commits his changes.
3. Will these changes be reflected in the diagrams of the other users as well if the user updates his copy.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it supposed to behave like this.

Why don't you try it?

1. Create a repository and local copy of version control.
2. Then from EA add packages to the version control and start testing.

Wonderfull material about EA with version control can be found here :
[Best Practices](http://www.sparxsystems.com/WhitePapers/Version_Control.pdf)

Implementation in EA is described clearly [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/downloads/resources/booklets/version_control_uml_models.pdf)

Creating SVN repository can be done easily with [visual svn](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/download/)

Creating local copies of svn can be done with [Tortoise svn](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)

Good luck!

Comment: First time I've read somebody calling Sparx documentation wonderful ;)

Comment: @sjaymj26, Do you need more help? Why don't you check the green tick?